# Maven build issue due to codehause termination

Tags: maven-2

As codehause services are terminated, I am getting this build error:

> *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '7226cd6d25
> 06216c083eb2a25d71db156ed7e3f3'; remote =  - RETRYING
> Downloading: repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/geronimo/genesis/config/c
> onfig/1.1/config-1.1.pom
> 318b downloaded
> [WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '7226cd6d25
> 06216c083eb2a25d71db156ed7e3f3'; remote =  - IGNORING
> [ERROR] BUILD ERROR

How do I change the codehause repository to another repository? Or is there any another way to handle this issue?

I have this dependency in my project:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
  <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This version does not exist in maven central and you should use maven central instead codehaus repository...which does not make sense.